# ** Operator Causing RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python-3.x, exponent

In a program I'm running, I have an issue where the exponent (**) operator in python is throwing a "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars" error, and I have no idea why.  The four specific lines causing this issue are:

```
mod = datumx ** (hold+1)
mod = datumy ** (hold+1)
mod = datumx ** (hold)
mod = datumy ** (hold)
```

Where hold is a value passed into the function that must be greater than 1 (in my test cases, I have it set at 1.2), datumx and datumy are the x and y components of an ordered pair passed in from a CSV file (all the points are between +2 and -2), and hold is just a variable meant to hold it (part of an attempt to figure out where the error was coming from).  Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Try to figure out the exact values that triggers the error. You can add a `print(datumx, datumy, hold)` befor the rows. Maybe you get a hint of what the problem is.